# Sign hash using asynchronous call

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I am using iText7 for performing PDF and signing operations. My scenario is I am computing hash on my local machine and sending this hash to signing server and in response get the signed PKCS1(Raw signature) and then I am embedding this signature into PDF.
My code snippet is as follows:

1: **Read public cert from smart card device.**

2: **Initialize PdfReader from original document bytes containing signature field named "Signature1"**

3: **Initialize PdfSigner and set signature appearance:**

```
PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(pdfReader, outputStream, new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode());
 pdfSigner.SetFieldName("Signature1");
 pdfSigner.GetDocument().GetCatalog().SetModified();
ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(handSignatureBytes);
PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = pdfSigner.GetSignatureAppearance();
 signatureAppearance.SetContact("contactInfo");
 signatureAppearance.SetLocation("locationInfo");
 signatureAppearance.SetPageNumber(1);
 signatureAppearance.SetReason("signingReason");
 signatureAppearance.SetSignatureGraphic(imageData);
 signatureAppearance.SetRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC);
 signatureAppearance.SetSignatureCreator("Malik");
 signatureAppearance.SetCertificate(x509Certificate);
```

4: **I have implemented IExternalSignatureContainer interface to get document hash:**

```
public class PreSigning : IExternalSignatureContainer
 {
 protected PdfDictionary sigDic;
 private byte[] hash;
public PreSigning(PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter)
 {
 sigDic = new PdfDictionary();
 sigDic.Put(PdfName.Filter, filter);
 sigDic.Put(PdfName.SubFilter, subFilter);
 }
public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)
 {
 signDic.PutAll(sigDic);
 }
public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
 {
 this.hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, DigestAlgorithms.GetMessageDigest("SHA256"));
 return new byte[0];
 }
public byte[] getHash()
 {
 return hash;
 }
public void setHash(byte[] hash)
 {
 this.hash = hash;
 }
 }
```

5: **Getting document hash:**

```
PreSigning external = new PreSigning(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
 pdfSigner.SignExternalContainer(external, estimatedSize);
byte[] documentHash = external.getHash();
```

6: **Initialize PdfPKCS7 class to get Data To Be Signed and getting hash of Data To Be Signed to send to signing server:**

```
PdfPKCS7 pdfPKCS7 = new PdfPKCS7(null, x509CertificatesChain, "SHA256", false);
 dataToBeSigned = pdfPKCS7.GetAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(documentHash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null);
byte[] dataToSignHash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(new MemoryStream(dataToBeSigned), DigestAlgorithms.GetMessageDigest("SHA256"));
```

7: **I have keep the outputStream from PdfSigner for signature embedding phase:**

```
documentStreamBytes = ((MemoryStream)outputStream).ToArray();
```

8: **Send the Data To Be Signed hash to signing server.**

9: **Get the PKCS1 data from signing server in response:**

```
byte[] PKCS1 = Convert.FromBase64String(preSigningResponse.signedHash);
```

10: **Initialized PdfPKCS7 class for getting PKCS7 from PKCS1:**

```
PdfPKCS7 pdf = new PdfPKCS7(null, x509CertificatesChain, "SHA256", false);
pdf.SetExternalDigest(PKCS1, null, "RSA");
byte[] pkcs7Data = pdf.GetEncodedPKCS7(documentHash, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS, null, null, null);
```

11: **Get the original document from documentStreamBytes:**

```
Stream pdfReaderStream = new MemoryStream(documentStreamBytes);
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfReaderStream);
PdfDocument originalDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter(new MemoryStream()));
```

12: **I have implemented IExternalSignatureContainer for signature embedding using PdfSigner.SignDeferred() method:**

```
public class PostSigning : IExternalSignatureContainer
 {
 protected byte[] _sig;
 public PostSigning (byte[] sign)
 {
 _sig = sign;
 }
 public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)
 {
 }
public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
 {
 return _sig;
 }
 }
```

13: **Calling PdfSigner.SignDeferred() method to get the final document:**

```
Stream resultStream = new MemoryStream();
IExternalSignatureContainer externalSignatureContainer = new PostSigning(pkcs7Data);
PdfSigner.SignDeferred(originalDocument, "Signature1", resultStream, externalSignatureContainer);
byte[] finalDoc = ((MemoryStream)resultStream).ToArray();
```

I am getting the following error:
Document has been altered or corrupted since the signature has been applied.

Can anyone help me regarding this scenario using iText7

Comment: Are you sure the `signerCert` includes a private key?

Comment: @mkl
No the private key is in the token which sign the hash and return pkcs1. 
Signer Cert is the public key

Comment: Ah, ok, I've been looking at your coffee some more. There are other issues. I'll answer later.

Comment: @mkl ok waiting for your answer

Comment: Did my answer clear up the issue?

Comment: @mkl
I have tried and implemented the solution suggested but I am still having a issue as PDF says the document has been altered or corrupted since the signature has been applied.

Comment: @mkl
I have updated the question and write all my code steps for clarification purpose.
The code is working with PKCS11 hardware devices and perform signing but it says document has been altered.

Comment: Can you share an example PDF signed with your code?

Comment: @mkl
The example PDF can be downloaded from the following link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nxbxmicfh6jjb19/SignedDocThroughCard-Suggested%20solution.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Ok, the signed hash and the hash of the authenticated attributes differ. Please make sure you really use the same inputs in steps 6 and 10. Furthermore, please make sure your signing server really wants the hash (and does not hash itself). As you only show small excerpts and not runnable code, I cannot test it.

Comment: @mkl
Thanks for the support. I have rechecked the inputs on mentioned steps and correct the input hashes. It works for me.
Regards

Comment: @mkl
Can you please guide me in following regards that I am now using iText7 version 7.1.8.0.
I am getting the error that: *There is no field in the document with such name: Signature1* on below line of code:

IExternalSignatureContainer externalSignatureContainer = new PostSigning(pkcs7Data);
PdfSigner.SignDeferred(originalDocument, "Signature1", resultStream, externalSignatureContainer);

Whereas the field with the same name exists in the PDF and can be extracted using PDFAcroForm.
Here is the document attached:
https://1drv.ms/b/s!AvIgyv7xAxxoigy6t0q3ZBHCl8ma?e=h6hnjZ

Comment: `PdfSigner.SignDeferred` requires a PDF which has been prepared for signature injection in the named signature field like the output of your steps 3..5 is. [Your example PDF](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AvIgyv7xAxxoigy6t0q3ZBHCl8ma?e=h6hnjZ) has not been prepared for signing yet.

Comment: @mkl
The same steps performed on other project with the same document and it is being processed perfectly.
Could you please guide me what is wrong in the example PDF with the signature?

Comment: Please share the PDF *after* preparation to allow analysis.

Comment: @mkl
There was issue at my end regarding the bytes which I have figured out and solve the problem. But now the signed document when opened in Adobe, it says *"Internal cryptographic library error, Error Code: 0x2726"*.

The signed PDF is attached here:
https://1drv.ms/b/s!AvIgyv7xAxxoig71U5b3uh3Cpwsd?e=iI9Alx

Comment: The actual signature has not been created by the private key associated with the alleged signer certificate.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous issues in your code.

#### Starting a signature twice

Foremost: In your second part (*Embed the returned PKCS1 into PDF*) you start again with the original file and create a new signature field therein. This results in a slightly different PDF than the one you prepared in your first part; thus, the signature value you have retrieved between the two parts obviously cannot be used for this new PDF.

You must change your architecture.

If you want to keep your two-step approach, you have to keep the file you created in your first part in `outputStream` and re-use it in the second part. And to fill in the retrieved signature, you must use `PdfSigner.signDeferred` instead of starting with a `new PdfSigner`.

Alternatively you can do it in one step, putting the signature server call into a custom `IExternalSignatureContainer` implementation.

#### Signing the wrong PDF data

In your first part you appear to set the `outputStream` contents as the data to sign (actually you even put it into a field that by its name, `responseObject.base64Hash`, should only hold a hash value; I don't understand that at all). But the bytes to sign are not the complete `outputStream` contents, a placeholder therein for the final signature value must be excluded.

You must only sign the resulting PDF without that placeholder. You can get it if instead of the `ExternalBlankSignatureContainer` as is you extend it by overriding the `byte[] Sign(Stream data)` method and grabbing the `Stream` parameter thereof. This stream contains exactly the bytes to sign.

#### The wrong signature format

You mention you get *the signed Pkcs1* from your signing server. What you need, though, is a CMS signature container.

If your signature server also offers to return CMS (or PKCS#7) signature containers, use that kind of call.

Otherwise you must build a CMS container yourself, e.g. using the iText `PdfPKCS7` class or BouncyCastle mechanisms.